# Suitable data structure for fast search on sets. imput: tags, output: sentence

Tags: python, database, search, set

I have the following problem.

I get 1-10 tags, related to an image, each have a probability of existence in image.

inputs: beach, woman, dog, tree ...

I would like to retrieve from database an already composed sentence which is most related to the tags.

e.g:

beach -> "fun at the **beach**" / "chilling on the **beach**" ....

beach, woman -> "**woman** at the **beach**"

beach, woman, dog - > none found!

take the closest exist but consider probability 
lets say: woman 0.95, beach 0.85, dog 0.7
so if exist take woman+beach(0.95, 0.85) then woman+dog and last beach+dog, the order is that higher are better but we are not summing.

I thought of using python **sets** but I am not really sure how.

Another option will be defaultdict:

db['beach']['woman']['dog'], but I want to get the same result also from:
db['woman']['beeach']['dog']

I would like to get a nice solution.
Thanks.

**EDIT: Working solution**

```
from collections import OrderedDict
list_of_keys = []
sentences = OrderedDict()
sentences[('dogs',)] = ['I like dogs','dogs are man best friends!']
sentences[('dogs', 'beach')] = ['the dog is at the beach']
sentences[('woman', 'cafe')] = ['The woman sat at the cafe.']
sentences[('woman', 'beach')] = ['The woman was at the beach']
sentences[('dress',)] = ['hi nice dress', 'what a nice dress !']


def keys_to_list_of_sets(dict_):
    list_of_keys = []
    for key in dict_:
        list_of_keys.append(set(key))

    return list_of_keys

def match_best_sentence(image_tags):
    for i, tags in enumerate(list_of_keys):
        if (tags & image_tags) == tags:
            print(list(sentences.keys())[i])

list_of_keys = keys_to_list_of_sets(sentences)
tags = set(['beach', 'dogs', 'woman'])
match_best_sentence(tags)
```

results:

```
('dogs',)
('dogs', 'beach')
('woman', 'beach')
```

This solution run over all keys of an ordered dictionary,
o(n), I would like to see any performance improvement.

Comment: As far as I understand your issue, you don't know what data structure to choose to store your tag pairs?

Comment: How big is the database? how many sentences and keywords does it contain? Is it static or does it change dynamically adding and removing new sentences?

Comment: static, not changing.

Comment: 1000 sentences and growing...

Comment: @SamperMan I don't really know what I don't know. I don't have a proper solution for both storing and retrieving.

Comment: The find done once in few seconds, but this application runsX500 instances, so it need to be not so slow.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be the simplest way of doing this without using DBs would be to keep sets for each word and take intersections.

More explicitly:

If a sentence contains the word "woman" then you put it into the "woman" set. Similarly for dog and beach etc. for each sentence. This means your space complexity is O(sentences*average_tags) as each sentence is repeated in the data structure.

You may have:

```
>>> dogs = set(["I like dogs", "the dog is at the beach"])
>>> woman = set(["The woman sat at the cafe.", "The woman was at the beach"])
>>> beach = set(["the dog is at the beach", "The woman was at the beach", "I do not like the beach"])
>>> dogs.intersection(beach)
{'the dog is at the beach'}
```

Which you can build into an object which is on top of defaultdict so that you can take a list of tags and you can intersect only those lists and return results.

Rough implementation idea:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class myObj(object): #python2
    def __init__(self):
        self.sets = defaultdict(lambda: set()) 

    def add_sentence(self, sentence, tags):
         #how you process tags is up to you, they could also be parsed from
         #the input string. 
         for t in tags:
             self.sets[tag].add(sentence)

    def get_match(self, tags):
         result = self.sets(tags[0]) #this is a hack 
         for t in tags[1:]:
             result = result.intersection(self.sets[t])

         return result #this function can stand to be improved but the idea is there
```

Maybe this will make it more clear how the default dict and sets will end up looking in the object.

```
>>> a = defaultdict(lambda: set())
>>> a['woman']
set([])
>>> a['woman'].add(1)
>>> str(a)
"defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7fcb3bbf4b90>, {'woman': set([1])})"
>>> a['beach'].update([1,2,3,4])
>>> a['woman'].intersection(a['beach'])
set([1])
>>> str(a)
"defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7fcb3bbf4b90>, {'woman': set([1]), 'beach': set([1, 2, 3, 4])})"
```

Comment: I find this option as a good solution, but I would change one thing:
Instead of sentances I will put numbers, each number is a represantaion of a sentence in a list i.e. my_list[1] = 'dog at the beach', this way I will save memory.

Comment: We do miss the probability part

Comment: I forgot to mention that this solution doesn't address that, as I did not understand your intent. Numbers would speed it up, you could also wrap an object around each string, which may or may not be good depending on your problem.

Comment: I will post a solution based on your answer with the probability implemented.

Comment: I do got into situation where a sentence must have beach and woman but will not be valid for beach\woman by itself.

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends on the size of the database and on the number of combinations between keywords.  Moreover, it depends also on which operation you do most.
 If it's small and you need a fast `find` operation, a possibility is to use a dictionary with `frozensets` as keys which contain the tags and with values all the associated sentences.

For instance,

```
d=defaultdict(list)
# preprocessing
d[frozenset(["bob","car","red"])].append("Bob owns a red car")

# searching
d[frozenset(["bob","car","red"])]  #['Bob owns a red car']
d[frozenset(["red","car","bob"])]  #['Bob owns a red car']
```

For combinations of words like "bob","car" you have different possibilities according to the number of the keywords and on what matters more. For example

- you could have additional entries with for each combination
- you could iterate over the keys and check the ones that contain both *car* and *bob*

Comment: What if you want ["bob", "car"] as a lookup?

Comment: It depends, if the space is not an issue (i.e., small amount of keywords) you could have additional entries with all the combinations, otherwise iterating over the keys and check the ones that contain both car and bob.